# tabular: vertical align minipage in table (top)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I have a poster consisting of two columns. In one of the columns I have placed two figures next to each other. To get a nice tikz-frame around each figure I had to put them into minipages each (I did not managed to get just the tikz-frame around a figure working without a minipage...)

My problem is now, that I would like to have both elements [tikz-framed-figure] to be vertically aligned at the top. I tried to align it with tabular{x} but so far without success.

```
\documentclass[englisch,a0]{KITposter}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{cc}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[framed,double,ultra thick,draw=red,rounded corners=25pt] {
      \begin{minipage}[H]{.45\columnwidth}
        \begin{figure}
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{./setup_1.pdf}
        \label{fig:setup_1}
        \end{figure} 
      \end{minipage}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  &
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[framed,double,ultra thick,draw=red,rounded corners=25pt] {
      \begin{minipage}[H]{.45\columnwidth}
      \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{./network_1.pdf}
        \label{fig:network_1}
      \end{figure} 
      \end{minipage}
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**edit**

The solution suggested by Torbjørn (with a much more simplified structure without dead weight) works very well for me aligning the graphics within the tikz frames:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}[myframe/.style={double,ultra thick,draw=red,rounded corners=25pt,inner sep=10pt}]
\node [myframe] (imga) {\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{example-image}};
\node [right=of imga.north east,anchor=north west,myframe] {\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Cheers and thanks for the help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that you do not have to use the `figure` environment to use `\includegraphics`. In fact, as `figure` is a floating environment, it doesn't really make sense to put it inside a `minipage` in a `node` in a `tikzpicture` in a `tabularx`, all  of which doesn't float. Remove the `minipage` and `figure` environments, and the `\centering`.

Comment: Hi Torbjørn, including the packages sounds reasonable ;)
I have added them. The figure is mostly a remnant from playing around (with/without minipages etc.pp.)

Comment: (It wasn't me asking you to do that, but @LaRiFari.) Note also that it is best to avoid custom documentclasses unless they are required to demonstrate the problem. In this case I guess the standard `article` would be just as good?

Comment: ah, yes - sorry for the custom class (my universities corporate design requirements...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(My suggestion in the comment to LaRiFaRi's answer was a bit uncomplete, so here is a more complete answer.)

You can do this with a single `tikzpicture`, placing each image in a separate node. Instead of using the `backgrounds` library and modifying the style of the background rectangle, define a new style and apply this to each node. There is one addition of `inner sep=10pt` to keep the frame from covering the corners of the images.

The positioning is handled by the `positioning` library of TikZ. I set the second node to be `right=of imga.north east`, and then set `anchor=north west`. This means that the top of the two images are aligned.

The reason you got overlap is that you didn't use my code. You wrote `right of=` instead of `right=of`. See [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386) for an explanation of why that occurs

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[myframe/.style={double,ultra thick,draw=red,rounded corners=25pt,inner sep=10pt}]
    \node [myframe] (imga) {\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \node [right=of imga.north east,anchor=north west,myframe] {\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! It is working like a charm, The graphics are aligned at the top. Good to know about the differences between "right=of" / "right of="

Answer (score 3):

With `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,
        enhanced,
        raster force size=false,
        size=fbox,
        raster column skip=4mm,
        raster right skip= 0pt,
        raster left skip=0pt,
        raster valign=top,
        boxrule=2pt,arc=2mm,
        colframe=red,colback=blue!50!black,
        drop fuzzy shadow]
      \tcbincludegraphics[hbox,graphics options={width=0.42\linewidth}]{example-image-a}
      \tcbincludegraphics[hbox,graphics options={width=0.42\linewidth}]{example-image-10x16}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}    

\begin{document}    
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{YY}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,background rectangle/.style={double,ultra thick,draw=red,rounded corners=25pt}] % change corner size to smaller values in order to prevent touching.
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{./setup_1.pdf}
        %\label{fig:setup_1} % you do not need a label if there is no caption.
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,background rectangle/.style={double,ultra thick,draw=red,rounded corners=25pt}]
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{./network_1.pdf}
        %\label{fig:network_1} % you do not need a label if there is no caption.
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Torbjørn, the new defined column type did not improved the alignment with both graphics with different heights 
https://imgur.com/9Pfeezr

Comment: without table the horizontal alignment is not working (right of fails somewhat), also the vertical alignment is still centred
    \begin{tikzpicture}[myframe/.style={double,ultra thick,draw=red,rounded corners=25pt,inner sep=10pt}] 
      \node[myframe](imga)  {
          \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{./overview_1.pdf}
        };
        \node[right of=imga,myframe] {
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{./network_1.pdf}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

https://imgur.com/f5wxGfP